# Can not autowire the bean in the jar

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot can not autowire bean in the jar and caused error when it is loading.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.xxx.core.orm.XXXSqlTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 18 more
```

My Starter class is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.sds")
@Configuration
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);
    }

}
```

The class com.xxx.xxx.core.orm.XXXSqlTemplate is located in the jar and the jar is also included in the classpath.

How can I solve this? I changed tomcat to jetty as a embedded servlet container.
But is wasn't workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If the SqlTemplate class is not in a subpackage of `com.sds`, you have to add the package of the class (or a super package of that) to the ComponentScan annotation, like this:

`@ComponentScan({"com.sds", "com.xxx"})`